# XeLaTex, Biber, XeLaTeX mac terminal mactex2015

Tags: xetex, biber, mactex, latexmk, scripts

Want to compile with terminal.  Currently options that work in texmaker are

```
 "/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-darwin/xelatex" -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|
"/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-darwin/biber"%|"/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin
/x86_64-darwin/xelatex" -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

I tried `latexmk -xelatex ~/Documents/inProgress/main.tex`
this gives an error `! LaTeX Error: File title.tex not found.`

main.tex should include content from title.tex and references.bib before making the pdf

Comment: What does `cd ~/Documents/inProgress` followed by `latexmk -xelatex main` say?

Comment: `LaTeX Warning: Reference `footdir@14' on page 1 undefined on input line 30.

! Misplaced \noalign.
\hline ->\noalign 
                  {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule \@height \arrayrulewidth \futurelet...
l.47   \hline
             
?`

Comment: This means that you should run `latexmk` from the directory containing the main file. And to fix your TeX errors, now.

Comment: my command is `latexmk -xelatex -f main.tex`  I thought -f was just do it.  What's the "I don't want to hit enter 10 times just give me a pdf command?"

Comment: You have syntax errors in your TeX files; if you don't fix them…

Comment: thank you @egreg, it's working well from terminal now.  Do you know how to change Last, *Title*, Page. footcites to Last Year, Page? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268096/customizing-biblatex-chicago

Answer (score 1):

This means that you should run latexmk from the directory containing the main file.

Comment: Alternatively you can pass the `-cd` option to `latexmk`

Comment: I was typing latexmk -xelatex and then dragging the file onto the terminal.  Apparently that confuses latexmk about where to look for other included files like title.tex and bibliography.bib.

Comment: Writing `latexmk -xelatex -cd` and then dragging the file in should work.  The `-cd` option means `latexmk` changes to the directory of the file before starting the compilation.