# Biblatex-Chicago Author-Date in Footnote

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, biber, chicago-style

I have looked at [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-style) but still need some help.  I want a second non-consecutive footnote to be Author Year, p.

1. Mark Twain, *Tom Sawyer* (NY:NYU P.,1990), 201.
2. Ibid, 220.
3. Pauly Shore, *My Life* (London:HM P., 2001), 13-14.
4. Twain 1990, 21.

Currently`\usepackage[notes,backend=biber,bookpages=false,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false]{biblatex-chicago}`is giving me

4. Twain, *Tom Sawyer*, 201.

Here is my MWE

filename: stackexample2.tex

```
% this is compiled from commandline
%"latexmk -xelatex -f stackexample2.tex"

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{geometry,polyglossia,fontspec,csquotes,setspace}
\setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
     \usepackage[notes,backend=biber,bookpages=false,doi=false,isbn=false,url=    false]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\let\ac=\autocite
\bibliography{examplebib.bib}

\begin{document}

\doublespacing
The first ref looks fine.\ac[50]{NAHIR1978} Also a firstcite.
\autocite{kuzar} So is this one.\autocite[26]{horvath97} Ibids work     great.\autocite[26]{horvath97} Also this Ibid.\autocite[29-34]    {horvath97}  Here I want an Author-Date Style footnote. "Nahir 1978,     29."\ac[29]{NAHIR1978}" This one is "Kuzar 2001,45." Help me!     \autocite[45-46]{kuzar} First cite again.\autocite[201]{Wexler1990}Two     authors on a second cite should be Last and Last year, page."Horvath and         Wexler 1990, 55."\autocite[55]{horvath97}
Here is "Wexler 1990, 200."  Except it's not.\autocite[220]    {Wexler1990}
%\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

second filename:examplebib.bib

```
%% This BibTeX bibliography file was created using BibDesk.
%% Saved with string encoding Unicode (UTF-8) 

@book{Wexler1990,
Author = {Wexler, Paul},
Date-Added = {2015-09-17 17:22:17 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2015-09-17 17:22:17 +0000},
Isbn = {3447030631},
Pages = {146},
Publisher = {Wiesbaden: Otto Harrassowitz Verlag},
Title = {{The Schizoid Nature of Modern Hebrew: A Slavic Language in Search of a Semitic Past}},
Url = {https://books.google.com/books?id=q\_ebGe7FhVEC\&pgis=1},
Year = {1990},
Bdsk-Url-1 = {https://books.google.com/books?    id=q%5C_ebGe7FhVEC%5C&pgis=1}}

@book{kuzar,
Author = {Kuzar, Ron},
Publisher = {Berlin: Mouton de Gruyter},
Title = {Hebrew and Zionism: A Discourse Alalytic Cultural Study},
Year = {2001}}

@book{horvath97,
Author = {Horvath, Julia and Wexler, Paul},
Pages = {211},
Publisher = {Wiesbaden: Otto Harrassowitz Verlag},
Title = {{Relexification in Creole and Non-Creole Languages: With Special Attention to Haitian Creole, Modern Hebrew, Romani, and     Rumanian}},
Url = {https://books.google.com/books?id=XHd2ACl7l4UC\&pgis=1},
Year = {1997},
Bdsk-Url-1 = {https://books.google.com/books?id=XHd2ACl7l4UC%5C&pgis=1}}

@article{NAHIR1978,
Author = {Nahir, Moshe},
Booktitle = {International Journal of the Sociology of Language},
Journal = {International Journal of the Sociology of Language},
Number = {18},
Pages = {49-68},
Title = {{Normativism and Educated Speech in Modern Hebrew}},
Volume = {1978},
Year = {1978},
Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/ijsl.1978.18.49}}
```

Accepted Answer: works !

```
\documentclass[a4paper,hebrew,british,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{geometry,polyglossia,fontspec,csquotes,setspace}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
    \usepackage[notes,backend=biber,bookpages=false,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false, labeldate]{biblatex-chicago}
\let\it=\textit
\let\ac=\autocite
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Times New Roman}[Script=Hebrew]
\bibliography{Referencesv6.bib}

%\begin Chicago-Author Date Footnotes Changes
\makeatletter
. . .  insert code here from answer . . . 
\makeatother
%\end of my Chicago-Author Date Footnotes Changes

\begin{document}

\input{./title.tex} 

\doublespacing
Was the\ac[50]{NAHIR1978} Also a firstcite.
\autocite{kuzar} So is this one.\autocite[26]{horvath97} Ibids work great. \autocite[26]{horvath97} Also this.\ac[29]{NAHIR1978}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: sample output success!]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off the obligatory warning. With this change you deviate from the CMS citation requirements. Use at your own risk.

Secondly, since `biblatex-chicago` is purpose-built to implement the wishes of the CMS the result presented here might (a) not be entirely pleasing from an aesthetic as well as a usability point of view, you are essentially mixing an "authoryear" and "authordate" style here and (b) not give the expected result in corner cases.

First off we need to make sure we can do year disambiguation (otherwise we get into trouble with two works from the same year by the same set of authors), so we need the option `labeldate`.

Then we only need to change the `cite:short` macro to include the year instead of the title and add the `extrayear` information to the bibliography. Finally we make sure the separator between name and year is a space.

```
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
  \ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR%
    \ifentrytype{inreference}\OR%
    \ifentrytype{reference}\OR%
    \ifentrytype{mvreference}}%
  {\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{magazine}% Simplify .bib creation
    {\ifuseauthor%
      {\printfield[journaltitle]{journaltitle}\isdot\newcunit}%
      {}}%
    {\ifentrytype{manual}%
      {\printlist{organization}\isdot\newcunit}%
      {}}}%
  {\iffieldequalstr{authortype}{anon}%
    {\bibleftbracket\printnames{labelname}%
      \bibrightbracket\classicpunct}%
    {\iffieldequalstr{authortype}{anon?}%
      {\bibleftbracket\printnames{labelname}?%
        \bibrightbracket\classicpunct}%
      {\usebibmacro{choose+labelname}%\printnames{labelname}%
        \isdot\classicpunct}}}%
  \ifboolexpr{%
    togl {cms@allshort}%
    or
    test {\ifbibliography}%
  }%
  {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield{labelyear}\printfield{extrayear}}}% changes to this macro were here...
  {\printtext[cmshyperlink]{%
    \printfield{labelyear}\printfield{extrayear}}}}%:\thefield{entrytype}? ... and here

\renewbibmacro*{cmsorigdate}{% New for 0.9
  \iftoggle{cms@switchdates}%
  {\printdateextra}%
  {\printorigdate}}

\renewbibmacro*{cmsyear}{%
  \iftoggle{cms@switchdates}%
  {\printfield{origyear}}%
  {\printfield{year}\printfield{extrayear}}}

\renewbibmacro*{date}{% New for 0.9
  \iftoggle{cms@switchdates}%
  {\printorigdate}%
  {\printdateextra}}

\renewcommand{\classicpunct}{\setunit*{\addspace}}
\makeatother
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[notes,backend=biber,bookpages=false,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,labeldate]{biblatex-chicago}
\let\ac=\autocite
\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
  \ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR%
    \ifentrytype{inreference}\OR%
    \ifentrytype{reference}\OR%
    \ifentrytype{mvreference}}%
  {\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{magazine}% Simplify .bib creation
    {\ifuseauthor%
      {\printfield[journaltitle]{journaltitle}\isdot\newcunit}%
      {}}%
    {\ifentrytype{manual}%
      {\printlist{organization}\isdot\newcunit}%
      {}}}%
  {\iffieldequalstr{authortype}{anon}%
    {\bibleftbracket\printnames{labelname}%
      \bibrightbracket\classicpunct}%
    {\iffieldequalstr{authortype}{anon?}%
      {\bibleftbracket\printnames{labelname}?%
        \bibrightbracket\classicpunct}%
      {\usebibmacro{choose+labelname}%\printnames{labelname}%
        \isdot\classicpunct}}}%
  \ifboolexpr{%
    togl {cms@allshort}%
    or
    test {\ifbibliography}%
  }%
  {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield{labelyear}\printfield{extrayear}}}%
  {\printtext[cmshyperlink]{%
    \printfield{labelyear}\printfield{extrayear}}}}%:\thefield{entrytype}?

\renewbibmacro*{cmsorigdate}{% New for 0.9
  \iftoggle{cms@switchdates}%
  {\printdateextra}%
  {\printorigdate}}

\renewbibmacro*{cmsyear}{%
  \iftoggle{cms@switchdates}%
  {\printfield{origyear}}%
  {\printfield{year}\printfield{extrayear}}}

\renewbibmacro*{date}{% New for 0.9
  \iftoggle{cms@switchdates}%
  {\printorigdate}%
  {\printdateextra}}

\renewcommand{\classicpunct}{\setunit*{\addspace}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
The first ref looks fine.\ac[50]{sigfridsson} Also a firstcite.
\autocite{geer} So is this one.\autocite[26]{worman} Ibids work     great.\autocite[26]{worman} Also this Ibid.\autocite[29-34]{worman}  Here I want an Author-Date Style footnote. "Nahir 1978,     29."\ac[29]{sigfridsson}" This one is "Kuzar 2001,45." Help me!     \autocite[45-46]{geer} First cite again.\autocite[201]{baez/article}Two     authors on a second cite should be Last and Last year, page."Horvath and         Wexler 1990, 55."\autocite[55]{worman}
Here is "Wexler 1990, 200."  Except it's not.\autocite[220]{baez/article}

Lorem\autocite{knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c} ipsum\autocite{knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, I had only got as far as researching "\AtEveryCitekey{\ifciteseen{" when you posted.

Comment: @paynito Always a pleasure, never a chore!

Comment: Will it be a problem that I have to use polyglossia instead of babel?

Comment: @paynito No, that should not be a problem. I just couldn't be bothered to compile the document with XeLaTeX, so I used something I could run with pdfLaTeX.

Comment: @paynito It should really work. But you need to add the `labeldate` option to your call to `biblatex-chicago`, i.e. `\usepackage[notes,backend=biber,bookpages=false,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,labeldate]{‌​biblatex-chicago}`